# Ajax error due to intercepting a ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

Im trying to understand what happens when ajax calls are interrupted but not sure how to handle and capture it...

Here is my simple html file with ajax call -

1. The program performs a ajax call..(The ajax call does not return for minutes - added a timer on the view)..
2. There is another function that gets triggered every 5 seconds(this function will be actually triggered when there is no action on keyboard/mouse which I have not added it now)..After the 15 seconds, the page gets redirected to the main page..

3.The code works as expected but when the page is re-directed the ajax calls throws me an error. 
Error msg - "Error requesting /first_ajax_call: 0 error"

Question:

In my case, this error should not be thrown..I have to handle as a normal condition...How can I handle it?

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% load staticfiles %}

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var incr = 0;
    setInterval(refresh, 5000);
    function refresh()
    {
        incr = incr + 1
        alert("setinterval callling incr = " + incr )
        if (incr >= 3){
            window.location.assign("./")
        }

    }

    $(document).ajaxError(function(e,xhr,opt){
        alert("Error requesting " + opt.url + ": " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
      });

        $.ajax({
            //async:false
            url:'/first_ajax_call'
            ,type: 'GET'
            ,success: function(res,status,xhr){
                    alert('first_ajax_call complete')
            }
            //,error: function(msg){
            //  alert("Call to getproductinfo failed")
            //}
        })
        alert('after ajax call')
})
</script>
</head>
<body>
This is the page that will be redirected
</body>
</html>
```

view handler

```
def first_ajax_call(request):
    import time
    time.sleep(300)
    return  HttpResponse(json.dumps('a'),content_type='application/json')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are returning a http response with the content type `'application/json'` the appropriate method to call is `$.getJSON()`

```
$.getJSON('first_ajax_call')
.done(function( json ) {
alert('first_ajax_call complete');
})
.fail(function( jqxhr, textStatus, error ) {
var err = textStatus + ", " + error;
alert("Call to getproductinfo failed: " + err) 
});
```